# Pinout on a USB 3.0 connection to down-rate to USB 2.0

Tags: usb

Simple question about backwards comparability with USB 3.0 from the header pinout side.  If I have a USB 3.0 header and I wish to connect a USB 2.0 device, is the following wiring correct according to the diagram below?

```
USB 2.0   USB 3.0
USB+5V    Vbus
LP-       IntA_P1_D-
LP+       IntA_P1_D+
GND       GND
```

[image: USB 3.0 vs 2.0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that looks correct from the connector perspective.

Note that you should ideally pay attention to how you assemble a cable, for example shielding and twisted pairs for the D+/D- pins.

A very short adapter is unlikely to have any effect, but a longer cable may play havoc with the required USB tolerances (e.g. max capacitance).

You can buy inexpensive ready made adapters, which might be a good idea if this is a commercial product. Just search for “internal USB3 to USB2”.

Comment: Do you somehow know what is the ID pin for?